# Pass data from controller to javascript via Ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller queries the database based on the country selected in the view. I need to pass the country values to JavaScript via Ajax.
View to select country:
/app/views/things/index.html.erb

```
<ul id = "countries">
   <% @countries.each do |c| %>
       <li><%= link_to c.name, {controller: "things", action: "graph", :id => c.id}, remote: true -%></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>

<!-- Selected country is displayed as the current params -->
<div id="current-params"></div>
```

Routes:

```
/config/routes.rb
resources :things
get 'things/graph/:id' => 'things#graph'
```

Controller:
/app/controllers/things_controller.rb

```
def graph
    @country = Country.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end
 end
```

Controller sends the data to js.erb:
/app/views/things/graph.js.erb

```
$("#current-params").html("<%= j render(partial: 'graph') %>");
```

graph.js.erb renders the partial:
/app/views/things/_graph.html.erb

```
<%= "Current params: #{@country.name}" %>
```

Current params: Cameroon
I selected Cameroon and it was displayed as the output in the view as #current-params. Meaning that the cycle (view => controller => js.erb => partial => view) works.
Now I need to send the data from the controller to JavaScript by adding $ajax({}):
/app/views/things/graph.js.erb

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: 'things/graph/20', #I would like to generalize this to display the selected country, not just the country with ID 20. How do I specify an equivalent of params[:id] in js language?
   dataType: 'js',
   success: function (data) {
       alert("success");
       #then do something more like pass the data to D3 plot function
   },
   error: function (result) {
       alert("error");
   }
});
```

Back in the view when I select a country, I get a popup with the message "error" indicating that the Ajax call was not a success. How do I successfully get the data in JS?

The console output gave a 200 OK response:

```
Started GET "/things/graph/20" for 10.240.0.225 at 2017-05-13 11:11:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.240.0.225! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ThingsController#graph as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"20", "thing"=>{}}
  Country Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering things/graph.js.erb
  Rendered things/_graph.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered things/graph.js.erb (69.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 71.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Comment: To have your countries instead of an id, you should check the gem `friendly_id`

Comment: @jaeger will check out the `friendly_id` gem

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest solution to pass data from Ruby on Rails to JavaScript is [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon). It basically allows to write data to a `gon`-object within your controller and access it in the view:

```
# your_controller.rb
def index
  gon.your_variable = "Foobar"
end
```

You can then access the object the same way as you wrote to it from within JavaScript.

Other than that, you can always just use Rails variables inside your HTML like so without any additional gems:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.your_variable = '<%= j @your_rails_variable %>';
<% end %>
```

You can then access everything through the `window`-object inside JavaScript.

Comment: I will explore gon and see how it wirks with the problem